# JQuery UI Draggable: If helper is set to clone, why aren't the applied classes of the draggable set to the clone?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I made a draggable with jQuery UI and set the helper option to 'clone'. If I start dragging the element the the clone is created and it works as expected, besides that the applied classes from the initial element aren't passed to the clone.
If I instead use a function for the helper option, which returns an element cloned by jQuery's clone function, the applied classes are transferred to the clone.

Check out this [JsBin](http://jsbin.com/vuwisaqite/1/edit?html,js,output)

I can live with that workaround, but I was wondering if that is the expected behaviour?

EDIT:

The draggable was initalized on an element with an id based selector. If I change the selector to select by class it works as expected. The initial classes get cloned as well. So the question is why is the behaviour different when selected by class or id.

Check out this [JsBin](http://jsbin.com/pozanojowu/1/edit?js,output)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the reason but I guess this is becouse of themeing jquery-ui. Without a theme (or the default theme) it is better to have a clean helper so you can style it the way you want. If the classes are applied to the helper as well you need to clear them first if you want to style your own helper. I hope you know what I mean. I know this is more theory than an answer.

Comment: Yes I know what you mean.

But the docs state: "If set to "clone", then the element will be cloned and the clone will be dragged."

So I expect the same behaviour as jquery's clone function.

Would be nice if someone of the jquery ui team could say something to this.

Comment: Yep, that would be great. But don't expect an answer far away from mine ;)